# Populating a variable with DetailsView textbox data value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, detailsview

When an ASP.Net DetailsView data is first displayed, can you tell me how to populate the variable shown in this coding?

I already tried this in the code-behind file but was shown an error that:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

This is the coding:

```
Protected Sub DetailsViewDetails_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DetailsViewDetails.DataBound

    Dim txtOriginalRegistrationFee As TextBox

    If DetailsViewDetails.CurrentMode = DetailsViewMode.Edit Then
        txtOriginalRegistrationFee = FindControl("TextBoxRegistrationFee")

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtOriginalRegistrationFee.Text) = False Then
            MsgBox(txtOriginalRegistrationFee)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This is from the aspx file:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RegistrationFee" SortExpression="RegistrationFee">
   <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxRegistrationFee" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RegistrationFee") %>'></asp:TextBox>
   </EditItemTemplate>

   <InsertItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxRegistrationFee" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RegistrationFee") %>'></asp:TextBox>
   </InsertItemTemplate>

   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="LabelRegistrationFee" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RegistrationFee", "{0:c}") %>'></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>

   <ItemStyle ForeColor="Blue" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

*** Update ***

I tried using this coding updated based on your help but still get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error when clicking the edit button of the DetailsView.

Comment: Which line is giving the error?

Comment: If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtOriginalRegistrationFee.Text) = False Then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FindControl function needs a control to search otherwise it will be searching the page (or content) level controls.

Try

```
txtOriginalRegistrationFee = DetailsViewDetails.FindControl("TextBoxRegistrationFee")
```

By the way your line with the MsgBox function will not work either.  MsgBox is for windows forms and will not work on the web.  You must use javascript for that type of functionality.  Plus, that function takes a string, not a control.

Answer (score 0):

I don't work in VB so bear with me.... The template is only rendered if your details view is in insert mode.

```
Dim txtOriginalRegistrationFee As TextBox

If DetailsViewDetails.CurrentMode = DetailsViewMode.Insert Then
    txtOriginalRegistrationFee = FindControl("TextBoxRegistrationFee")

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtOriginalRegistrationFee.Text) = False Then
        MsgBox(txtOriginalRegistrationFee)
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the coding. Is it possible to get the value when it's in edit mode like: If DetailsViewDetails.CurrentMode = DetailsViewMode.Edit Then ...?

Comment: You can use the same text box in both insert and edit mode. Just include it in both templates.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried it for edit mode but still get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. I think I need to use "New" but don't know to do that. Can you show a code sample on making txtOriginalRegistrationFee as a new object?

Comment: You will still need to check for the specific CurrentMode on your details view. If it is in EditMode, the controls within the InsertTemplate don't exist. The same goes for edit controls while in InsertMode.

Comment: Thanks andleer for the reply. I updated my post. Looks like I need to use the "New" keyword. Can you show me how to correct my coding by including that keyword?

Comment: One of us is lost... Your edit template in the markup does not contain a control named 'TextBoxRegistrationFee'. You need to change that. Also your ItemTemplate should only contain an Eval not a Bind since you don't need two way binding. I am not following your need for "new". Lastly, you can drop the "FindControl" logic in your Dim/declaration. You only need to find the control if you are in Edit mode.

Comment: You do not need the "new" keyword.  You changed your post to check for the edit mode when you should be checking for insert mode as @andleer stated.  The textbox for edit is named `TextBox1`.  The textbox for insert is named `txtOriginalRegistrationFee`.  Reread your code and this post and notice the differences.

Comment: nickles80, thanks for the reply. I made all the changes including fixing the markup but still get the same error. I will soon update my post to show all coding changes.